# Hide a pop message while downgrading using Installshield

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield, downgrade, installshield-2016

I was installing 3.2.0.2 version(older) over 3.2.0.3(latest) to verify downgrade.
However I get a pop-up message as `The setup will perform an upgrade....`,
and followed by another pop-up `A later version of ...`.

After the second pop-up, install operation just terminated (which is expected behavior). However, the issue is with first pop-up which shouldn't be displayed while downgrading.

How can I get rid of this first pop-up?

I tried disabling prompt, `don't prompt` options, but no luck.

I have searched the  `property manager` through string editor as well, but unable to find where is that message is coming from.

Could anyone please help me to get rid of this one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you are talking about. Please add some more detail

Comment: are you talking about changes in InstallShield code? also please provide more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: While doing downgrade operation, I am getting upgrade pop-up 1st, then downgrade pop-up. I want to disable upgrade pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, how much of your users will perform a downgrade of your software?

Is it not better to block downgrades?

What I do is showing a message to the user that a newer version is already installed and if he wants to install the older version, he first needs to remove the installed version.

Comment: The same thing I am doing. Showing a message to user. However before showing the downgrade message, one extra pop-up I am getting. I want to avoid the extra message.

Comment: @BidarvaB I assume you use the upgrade table to look for previous versions of your product?! Have you read the windows installer help about the upgrade table and especially this line in the explanation of the VersionMin and VersionMax columns: 'VersionMin/VersionMax must be a valid product version as described for the ProductVersion property. Note that Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the product version. If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field.'